# get index of splited sentences from a string list

Tags: python, string, text-mining

The desired result is either a function or a way to find where is a sentence within a list of strings.

```
sentence = 'The cat went to the pool yesterday'

structure = ['The cat went,', 'to the pool yesterday.','I wonder if you realize the effect you are having on me. It hurts. A lot.']
```

for example

```
def findsentence(sentence, list of strings):
      # do something to get the output, vec of positions to find the sentence in hte string list
return output

findsentence(sentence, structure)
> (0,1) # beacuse the phrase is splitted in the list...
```

## Caution!!

The challenge it is not to find exactly the sentence. Look at the example, this sentence is part of sentence position 0 and part in structure postition 1.

So this is not a simple, string manipulation problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following :

```
sentence = "foo sam bar go"
structure = ["rq", "foo sam", "bar go", "ca", "da"]

def findsentencelist(sentence, list_of_strings):
    l = []
    for item in list_of_strings:
        if item in sentence:
            l.append(list_of_strings.index(item))
    return l

print str(findsentencelist(sentence, structure))
```

Hopefully this will help you, Yahli.

EDIT :

There is a problem with your variables. 
Your sentence MUST be a string - not a list.
Edit your variables and try this function again :)

SECOND EDIT:
I think I've finally understood what you're trying to do. Let me know if this one works better.

THIRD EDIT:
Jesus, Hopefully this one would solve your problem. Let me know if it did the trick :)

Comment: Not working... returning None

Comment: It is. Just make sure that the sentence must be from a string type and not a  list! The correct way to set the variable is this : sentence = 'When I think about what you are doing'.

Comment: @PeCaDe, I've edited my answer accordingly. Please try it again and let me know if it worked for you!

Comment: the challegne is not to find exaclty the sentence you have tried. my example and question was with this one, sentence = 'When I think about what you are doing, I wonder if you realize the effect you are having on me', is composed with two srings from the string list!                   So, please caution with not to read properly the questions.

Comment: @PeCaDe, I've re-edited my answer. Please try it :)

Comment: the correct scenary would be.  sentence = "foo bar"
structure = ["sa", "foo", "bar", "ca", "da"]. And you find that your sentence is in the structure index 0 and 1.

Comment: @PeCaDe, Try it now. Please next time make sure you explain your question better :)

Comment: Thnks so much that was the right answer, I couldnt express my self properly. thx

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

I just remove punctuations on `structure` to make it work:

```
sentence = 'The cat went to the pool yesterday'

structure = ['The cat went,', 'to the pool yesterday.','I wonder if you realize the effect you are having on me. It hurts. A lot.','Life is too short as it is. In short, she had a cushion job.']

import string

def findsentence(sentence, list_of_strings):
    return tuple(i for i, s in enumerate(list_of_strings) if s.translate(None, string.punctuation) in sentence)


print findsentence(sentence, structure)
# (0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

After removing the punctuation. You can use this code to get the index ,

```
for i,j in enumerate(structure):
     if j in sentence:
          print(i)
```

Hope this solves your problems. There are quite other solutions as python is flexible.